# read user input string with space between quotes in C

Tags: c

I have to read a user input that look like this one:

```
1 "string with space between quotes" 9.99
```

I want to store the number at the beginning of the input into an integer variable, the string between quotes into a string and the number at a double variable. I am using `fgets()` to get the string, but the problem is that the `fgets()` function keeps reading the user input until I type 0 and the number at the end of the input goes together with the string. scanf function doesn't do the job either, since it stops reading at the first space. My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
  int code;
  char description[50];
  double value;

  printf("Type in: ");
  scanf("%d", &code);
  fgets(description, 50, stdin);
  scanf("%lf", &value);

  printf("%d\n", code);
  printf("%s\n", description);
  printf("%2.2f", value);
}
```

Any ideas of how to read and store separately this 3 inputs considering they have to be at the same line?

Comment: scanf("%d \"%[^\"]\" %lf", &x, y, &z); note that this will not include the "

Comment: @robin.koch I don't think that will cope with spaces in the string?

Comment: %[^\"] means match until "

Comment: @or1426 http://ideone.com/d2hRAX

Comment: @robin.koch oops. I managed to forget to recompile the program I was running so the binary was out of sync with the code I had. Probably I've been spending too much time doing interpreted stuff! I was going a bit insane trying to work out why your (correct) code didn't seem to be working. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Do you only need to cope when the contents of the line is *always* correct, or do you need to be able to cope with their being a mistake, like a double quote (") missing, or one of the numbers missing, or extra characters on the line? Asked a different way, is the input from a human being, or is it from a program? And is the size of the description array, 50, dictated by the specification you are trying to do, or is it an initial estimate?

Answer (score 4):

OP's approach hopes to use `fgets()` to read a portion of a line, yet `fgets()` reads until an end-of-line `'\n'` is encountered.

Read the *entire* line with `fgets()` and *then* parse.

Using `"%n"` is an easy way to see if the entire string was parsed as expected.

```
int code;
char description[50];
double value;
#define MAX_LINE_SIZE (20 + 2 + sizeof description + 2 + 20 + 2)
char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];

printf("Type in: ");
fflush(stdout);
fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);

int n = 0;
sscanf(line, "%d \"%49[^\"]\"%lf %n", &code,  description, &value, &n);
if (n == 0 || line[n] != '\0') {
  fputs("Input formatted incorrectly\n", stderr);
  return 1;
}

printf("%d\n", code);
printf("\"%s\"\n", description);
printf("%2.2f", value);
```

`"%d \"%49[^\"]\"%lf %n"` details

`"%d"` scan & toss whitespace, scan and save integer
`" "` scan and toss any whitespace
`"\""` scan and match a `'\"'`
`"%49[^\"]"` scan up to 49 char that are not `'\"'`, save in `description` and append `'\0'`
`"%lf"` scan & toss whitespace, scan and save `double`
`"%n"` save current offset of scan into `n`.

Comment: Much better to use `fgets()` + `sscanf()`, gives a lot of control on input validation.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (scanf("%d \"%49[^\"]\" %lf", &x, y, &z) == 3)
    …process valid data…
else
    …report erroneous input…
```

The relevant part for you is `%49[^\"]`; it matches a string until `"` is encountered (or it runs out of space). Note that this will not include the `"` into the string.